# Add multiple images from google drive in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api, blazor

I have an upload button on my view like this :

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <label class="col-form-label">Select Files</label>
     <input type="file" asp-for="Files" id="materialfiles" class="form-control" multiple />
     <span asp-validation-for="Files" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
```

When using mobile to upload multiple images from google drive (using drive from file explorer), it gives this error :
`ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED`
I couldn't find ways around this anywhere.
Should I use a library to upload multiple images or is there any way around this error ?

Comment: You are uploading them at one time?  Or one by one?  Chrome I believe doesn't allow you to change the file.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 In chrome all at one time.
In firefox , it only allows one at a time, but I am looking for bulk upload

Comment: Okay, so you are on a WIndows machine, and Google Drive is acting as a virtual drive?  Or are all your file actually mirrored on yoru system?